# When to set reuse=True for multi GPU training in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am trying to train a network with tensorflow with multiple towers. I had set `reuse = True` for all the towers. But in the [cifar10 multi gpu train of tensorflow tutorials](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py), the reuse variable has set after the first tower was created:

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
  for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
      with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (cifar10.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
        # Dequeues one batch for the GPU
        image_batch, label_batch = batch_queue.dequeue()
        # Calculate the loss for one tower of the CIFAR model. This function
        # constructs the entire CIFAR model but shares the variables across
        # all towers.
        # Actually the logits (whole network) is defined in tower_loss
        loss = tower_loss(scope, image_batch, label_batch)

        # Reuse variables for the next tower.
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

Does it make any difference? What happens if we set reuse=True beforehand?

Comment: How do you set `reuse = true` for all tower? pls show code

Comment: @Freundlicher suppose I pass it as an argument to `tf.variable_scope`. The model is inception resnet and the code is huge so I prefer to keep the question brief

Comment: You set `reuse=True` to `reuse` this node. For example, if you are building two almost different big networks with a shared RNN layer. You need to set `reuse=True` to this shared RNN layer. In short, if you want to use this layer more than once in a graph, you need to set `reuse=True`.

Comment: @Sraw Yes I know reuse is used to share variables. My question is, why they did `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` right after defining the network for the first time and not beforehand?

Comment: @Sraw You have to do it for each tower, so how do you want to do this outside the loop for the GPU numbers? pls show me the code :D

Comment: It is a little unclear, but I guess I have understood what you mean. I think there shouldn't be any difference, but I'm not sure. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to [share variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables).

Either version 1:

```
with tf.variable_scope("model"):
  output1 = my_image_filter(input1)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
  output2 = my_image_filter(input2)
```

or version 2:

```
with tf.variable_scope("model") as scope:
  output1 = my_image_filter(input1)
  scope.reuse_variables()
  output2 = my_image_filter(input2)
```

Both methods share the variable. The second method is used in the [Cifar10 tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L172) because it is much cleaner (and that's only my opinion). You can try to rebuild it with version 1, the code will probably be less readable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `reuse=False` for the first run to generate variables. It is an error if reuse=True but the variable is not yet constructed.

If you use a newer version of tensorflow (>1.4 I think) you can use `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` and it will do the magic for you.

I'm not sure how this interacts with the multi device setup you have. Double check if the variable names don't become prefixed by the device. In that case there's no reuse, each device has a different variable.